# Facebook Integration and Page Reloads

Tags: jquery, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a website that uses Facebook integration.  Every time any page reloads or any page navigation occurs, the Facebook-supplied scripts re-execute and a noticeable delay occurs until the user's profile context become available.  This seems inefficient and creates a perception of site delays.

Are there any recommended solutions that would mitigate this?  Is it feasible to preserve the logged-in user's Facebook ID in my own cookie that I create after they connect the first time?  Then I could access that immediately without waiting for the sometimes-sluggish Facebook API.  I would have to create a way to detect when the user logged out of Facebook (via a different browser window), however.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The API is probably sluggish because the channelUrl is not setup correctly in the FB.init() command.

Comment: You're right, this seemed to help greatly!  Found documentation on the "optional but recommended" channelUrl setting here: http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/530/

Comment: Excellent, glad to hear it help  :)